# overflow-x also hides overflow-y

Tags: html, css

There are multiple questions named this way, but I didn't find one that applies to my case, so here I am:

In this snippet:

```css
#container:hover {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2em;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    a<br/>
    b<br/>
    hover<br/>
    me
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that `overflow-x`, which is applied when you hover the red box, will also hide the overflow-y (at least on Chrome). This is annoying because I have a tooltip that I would like to be able to overflow above the red box, and in the meantime I have a menu that will slide from the right side and that should stay hidden.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: "Is this a bug?" maybe not a bug but as far I know it is a result of CSS specification and expected behaviour.

Comment: Well... Can you point me to where you see this? From what I read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-clip-edge) this is not what I understand overflow-x is supposed to be doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue - in the first answer there is a quote from W3C spec, but they probably updated the content of that page and maybe the spec too.

Comment: Well even with this sentence, the behavior we see here doesn't match. We don't have overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: (visible -> auto). We have overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: (visible -> hidden).

Comment: I mean it caused by the same thing some connections between those to do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the way `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` behave (it's the same in Firefox and other browsers), but you can change the way your HTML is organized.

Put everything that you want to hide when overflowing in a single wrapper. Put your tooltip in another wrapper.

Something like this may suit your needs:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  background: #f77;
  margin: 3em 2em;
}

#child {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #dd2;
  transition: .2s;
}

#child:hover #menu {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    hover<br/>
    me
    <div id="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tooltip">
    a<br/>
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Is the clipping behavior a bug?

No, the clipping is [in accordance with the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#scrolling-direction).

> UAs must clip the scrollable overflow area of scroll containers on the
> block-start and inline-start sides of the box (thereby behaving as if
> they had no scrollable overflow on that side).

In your case, the "block-start" side is the top, and the "inline-start" side is the left. That's why you can put your tooltip *below* the content, and it will trigger a scrollbar.

```css
#container:hover {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2em;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    hover<br/>
    me<br/>
    a<br/>
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

So why is it possible to *scroll* to content overflowing below the box, but not possible to simply make it *visible*? The reason is that when **any** `overflow` property is set to [`hidden`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-hidden), the entire box becomes a [scroll container](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#scroll-container).

> [A scroll container] allows the user to scroll clipped parts of its
> scrollable overflow area into view.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a bit complicated to do, as I'm using React and the tooltip is a component of the Button...
But if we all agree that the spec is not respected here, isn't this a bug?

Comment: @Sharcoux I added info about the spec to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: clip`, which does not turn the box into a scroll container. If you clip in both direction, you can also adjust the distance at which clipping occurs as well using [`overflow-clip-margin`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-clip-margin) :

```css
#container:hover {
  overflow-x: clip;
}


#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2em;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    aazkopekzapoekzapoekzapoekzapoekpozakepozakepozakeoza<br/>
    b<br/>
    hover<br/>
    me
  </div>
</div>
```